# MQTT.js subscriber receives duplicates message after disconnect-reconnect

Tags: node.js, mqtt

I'm trying to create a persistent session with MQTT.js and everything seems to work fine except one thing, as the title says.
I'm also using QoS 2 so the client should receive exactly 1 message without duplicates

here is the code:

**broker.js**
shouldn't matter

**publisher.js**

```
const mqtt = require("mqtt");

const getWeather = require("./api-clients/openWeatherMap/openWeatherMapClient");

const client = mqtt.connect("mqtt://localhost", {
  port: 1883,
  clean: false,
  clientId: "mqttjs_" + Math.random().toString(16).substr(2, 8),
});

client.on("connect", () => {
  console.log("connected");
  let i = 0;
  setInterval(() => {
    var weatherPromise = Promise.resolve(getWeather("Milan"));

    weatherPromise.then((data) => {
      var object = JSON.parse(data).coord;
      client.publish("Weather", i + " " + JSON.stringify(object), {
        qos: 2,
      });
      i++;
    });
  }, 5000);
});
```

**subscriber.js**

```
const mqtt = require("mqtt");

const client = mqtt.connect("mqtt://localhost", {
  port: 1883,
  clean: false,
  clientId: "mqttjs_1",
});

client.on("connect", () => {
  client.subscribe("Weather", { qos: 2 });
});

client.on("message", (message) => {
  context = message.toString();
  console.log(context);
});
```

and this is what the client subscriber receives:

- 0 {"lon":12.2214,"lat":46.145}
- 1 {"lon":12.2214,"lat":46.145}

subscriber.js disconnects for some time then it reconnects and as expected it receives:

- 2 {"lon":12.2214,"lat":46.145}
- 3 {"lon":12.2214,"lat":46.145}
- 4 {"lon":12.2214,"lat":46.145}
- 5 {"lon":12.2214,"lat":46.145}

then, after it disconnects and reconnects again, it receives:

- 3 {"lon":12.2214,"lat":46.145}
- 6 {"lon":12.2214,"lat":46.145}
- 7 {"lon":12.2214,"lat":46.145}

and I don't really know why it receives message 3 again.
and if I disconnect and reconnect it keeps doing this.

Comment: Edit: the duplicated message is the last message sent while the subscriber was disconnected

Comment: Edit 2: adding QoS: 1 fixed the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested the issue and haven’t received duplicate messages, but it seems that there was an issue in a previous version of MQTT.js, but I found that it was fixed. Maybe you can pre-test with the MQTT client first, not sure if it could be your MQTT Broker, recommend using MQTT X: http://mqttx.app/ to verify your MQTT Broker. If it's the same issue, it's probably not a code issue with the client you wrote.

Just in case if you would like to check the MQTT.js tutorial: https://www.emqx.com/en/blog/mqtt-js-tutorial